# Getting bigger artwork images from iTunes web search

Tags: itunes-store, itunesartwork

I'm fetching song information using the [iTunes Store web service search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

The only problem I've got, is that the resolution of the artwork is extremely low (only 60x60px or 100x100px available).

> **artworkUrl100, artworkUrl60**:  A URL for the artwork associated with the returned media type, sized to 100x100 pixels or 60x60 pixels.

Is there a way to get bigger sizes of those album images?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

iTunes offers a 600x600 version of the image as well - simply change the 100x100 in the image URL to 600x600.

The dimensions of the 600x600 image have one dimension that is up to 600px.  Books and movies, for instance, are not square so the image will be 600px tall but not 600px wide.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! ; ) I tried 200, 300, 500 and then gave up…

Comment: When I pull podcasts, I see artworkUrl600. If I pull movies, books, or audiobooks, I'm only seeing artworkUrl60, artworkUrl100, and sometimes artworkUrl30. Does the type of fetch make a difference (i.e. lookup versus search, or parameters used)? Quite frustrating!

Comment: 400x400 also works!
http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Features/v4/e3/e6/2d/e3e62d43-0088-c629-c3c1-cb82b4b03e6f/dj.ratvmowf.400x400-75.jpg

Answer (score 12):

These are the ones I found:

- 30 × 30.
- 40 × 40.
- 60 × 60.
- 80 × 80.
- 100 × 100.
- 110 × 110.
- 130 × 130.
- 150 × 150.
- 160 × 160.
- 170 × 170.
- 200 × 200.
- 220 × 220.
- 230 × 230.
- 250 × 250.
- 340 × 340.
- 400 × 400.
- 440 × 440.
- 450 × 450.
- 460 × 460.
- 600 × 600.
- 1 200 × 1 200.
- 1 400 × 1 400.

However, not all iTunes albums have that image size.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete list of artwork sizes available from iTunes (as of 10 November 2014)

```
30x30
40x40
60x60
80x80
100x100
110x110
130x130
150x150
160x160
170x170
190x190
200x200
220x220
230x230
240x240
250x250
340x340
400x400
440x440
450x450
460x460
480x480
600x600
1200x1200
1400x1400
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the largest image size available by replacing `100x100bb` with `100000x100000-999`. I've gotten some images that are 3000x3000. Thanks to Ben Dodson for this find: https://bendodson.com/projects/itunes-artwork-finder/